# What are these red blanks in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Why vs code mark these blanks with red color?]

I was working on vue js in vs code, when i pressed some key this problem is happend,how to return to previous state?

Comment: what extension do you use?

Comment: Vue.js Extension Pack, vue-format, Vue Peek, Vetur

Comment: I didn't face such issue yet.
did you try to use only one pack? e.g Vetur?

Comment: This problem resolved itself! but i dont know how?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely searching for a space in either the file or workspace search. Just clear them to make it go away.